# How to make a reference to a normal java class from GWT server side

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, servlets, gwt-rpc

I am building my project using GWT plugin for Eclipse Galileo. When I was done with RPC between the server and client, I tried to make a reference in the GWT project to a normal Java class in non-GWT project, but everytime when I create an object of this class I get a `ClassNotFoundException`. I did the buildpath for the GWT project, but it still gives me the same exception. Is there a way to get it to work?

Comment: try showing us some code

Answer (score 0):

GWT compiles the code to Javascript, it is then run on the browser. You can write some Java classes that run inside a Servlet engine, the only way to get them to communicate is to use some form of RPC.

Comment: but what i know the server side code not translate to JavaScript, only the client side, you also can specify which packages you want to translate to JavaScript, you can done that from the module. (correct me if im wrong)

Comment: @Mohammed_Q If you want your stuff in GWT to be both visible to both the client and the server you need to put the files under the client folder

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, to make any object from any non-gwt-project in gwt-project you should make sure to disable the Google App Engine, its somehow make that class invisible.
thanks for all the suggestions